# Use Newton’s method to find the solution of $2x^3+5x-6=0$ by using the following steps

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

Use Newton’s method to find the solution of  $$2x^3+5x-6=0$$
by using the following steps

a)  Find, $f(0)$  where $$f(x)=2x^3+5x-6$$

b)  Find, $f(1)$  where $$f(x)=2x^3+5x-6$$

c)  Choose a guess point  $$x_0$$

d)  Perform the iterations, until the values stabilize to the 8-digits after the decimal sign.

my work

for a)

newton formula

$$x_{n+1}  = x_n -\frac{f(x_n )}{f'(x_n )}   $$ ,      for $n = 0,1,2,3,...$

$$f' (x)=6x^2+5$$

$$x_1=x_0-\frac{-6}{5}  $$

$$ F(0)= x_0- \frac{-6}{5}  $$

for b)

$$x_2=x_1-\frac{-6}{5} $$

for c)

Let $$x_0=1$$

$$x_1=1-\frac{-6}{5}=\frac{11}{5}$$

for d)

$$x_1=x_0-\frac{-6}{5}$$

$$x_2=x_1-\frac{-6}{5}$$

$$x_3=x_2-\frac{-6}{5}$$

$$x_4=x_3-\frac{-6}{5}$$

$$x_5=x_4-\frac{-6}{5}$$

is that correct ???

Comment: I would like to add that Newton's method does not, in general, give the roots of a polynomial. It approximates it to any desired degree of accuracy (doubling in decimal accuracy roughly each iteration) but it won't find the EXACT solution.

Comment: The goal of (a) and (b) is to see that $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$, so there is a root of the polynomial in the interval $[0,1]$. Once you know this, you can choose a point $x_0$ accordingly, (c).

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, Newton method updates the initial guess $x_0$ according to $$x_{n+1}  = x_n -\frac{f(x_n )}{f'(x_n )}$$ So, if $f(x)=2 x^3+5 x-6$, $f'(x)=6 x^2+5$, this gives, after simplification $$x_{n+1} =\frac{4 x_n^3+6}{6 x_n^2+5}$$ As AjmalW answered, choose $x_0=1$ and start repeating the iterations. You will find $x_1=\frac{10}{11}$, $x_2=\frac{11986}{13255}$ and so on until the convergence criteria is met.

Answer (score 0):

a) You have to determine $f(0)$, that is $f(0) = 2(0)^3+5(0)-6=\cdots$.

b) You have to determine $f(1)$. See above.

c) You have to guess a number, say $x_{0}=1$, since it's close to the zero point.

d) You have to solve $f(x)=0$ using the Newton's method. Since $f'(x_{0})=6x^{2}+5$, you have $$x_{1}  = x_0 -\frac{f(x_0 )}{f'(x_0 )} = 10/11$$ where $x_{0}=1$. Find also $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$ etc.